# How to get sub array?

Tags: perl

I have the code below:

```
@a = ((1,2,3),("test","hello"));
print @a[1]
```

I was expecting it to print

```
testhello
```

But it gives me `2`.

Sorry for the newbie question (Perl is a bit unnatural to me) but why does it happen and how can I get the result I want?

Comment: I guess from your expectations that you are used to PHP arrays.  PHP arrays were unnatural to me coming from Perl. :-)

Comment: @AndyLester LOL no man I don't know PHP... I am from Java and Ruby...

Comment: Re "So there is no nested array(by round brackets)?", The only thing the parens do is alter precedence. They don't create any variables, arrays or otherwise. There's no array involved in `((1,2,3),("test","hello"))`.

Comment: @ikegami I see. So array in Perl is always one dimensional right? What is a practical use of array vs array reference?

Comment: Again, there's no array involved in `((1,2,3),("test","hello"))`, just 5 constants and 3 list operators. These create scalars and list of scalars respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way Perl constructs `@a` is such that it is equivalent to your writing,

```
@a = (1,2,3,"test","hello");
```

And that is why when you ask for the value at index `1` by writing `@a[1]` (really should be `$a[1]`), you get `2`. To demonstrate this, if you were to do the following,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @a = ((1,2,3), ("test","hello"));
my @b = (1,2,3,"test","hello");
print "@a\n";
print "@b\n";
```

Both print the same line,

```
1 2 3 test hello
1 2 3 test hello
```

What you want is to create anonymous arrays within your array - something like this,

```
my @c = ([1,2,3], ["test","hello"]);
```

Then if you write the following,

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $c[1];
```

You will see this printed,

```
$VAR1 = [
          'test',
          'hello'
        ];
```

Comment: So there is no nested array(by round brackets)? If you want to create nested array you have to use array reference?

Comment: Correct, if you want to create something like a multi-dimensional array you would have to have references to other arrays which can be done by using square brackets (anonymous arrays).

Comment: @Jared: All `@a == @b` does is compare the *size* of the two arrays (5). What you have written implies that it compares the elements for equality.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for pointing that out, silly mistake on my part

Answer (score 6):

Perl lists are one-dimensional only, which means `(1,2,(3,4))` is automatically flattened to `(1,2,3,4)`. If you want a multidimensional array, you must use references for any dimension beyond the first (which are stored in scalars).

You can get any anonymous array reference with bracket notation `[1,2,3,4]` or reference an existing array with a backslash `my $ref = \@somearray`.

So  a construct such as `my $aref = [1,2,[3,4]]` is an array reference in which the first element of the referenced array is 1, the second element is 2, and the third element is another array reference.

(I find when working with multidimensional arrays, that it's less confusing just to use references even for the first dimension, but `my @array = (1,2,[3,4])` is fine too.)

By the way, when you stringify a perl reference, you get some gibberish indicating the type of reference and the memory location, like "ARRAY(0x7f977b02ac58)".

Dereference an array reference to an array with `@`, or get a specific element of the reference with `->`.

Example:

```
my $ref = ['A','B',['C','D']];
print $ref;                   # prints ARRAY(0x001)
print join ',', @{$ref};      # prints A,B,ARRAY(0x002)
print join ',', @$ref;        # prints A,B,ARRAY(0x002) (shortcut for above)
print $ref->[0];              # prints A
print $ref->[1];              # prints B
print $ref->[2];              # prints ARRAY(0x002)
print $ref->[2]->[0];         # prints C
print $ref->[2][0];           # prints C (shortcut for above)
print $ref->[2][1]            # prints D
print join ',', @{$ref->[2]}; # prints C,D
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation too! It solves my other questions :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're after an array of arrays.  So, you need to create an array of array references by using square brackets, like this:

```
@a = ([1,2,3],["test","hello"]);
```

Then you can print the second array as follows:

```
print @{$a[1]};
```

Which will give you the output you were expecting: `testhello`

Answer (score -4):

It's just a matter of wrong syntax:

```
print $a[1]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with that line. `perl -E'@a=1..4;say @a[1]'` prints out `2` as expected.